# Asyncio and Playwright scraping loop, How to await task to parse data at the end of the main function

Tags: web-scraping, python-asyncio, playwright-python

I am new to Asyncio and playwright. I have done as much research on my own but I still cannot figure out this after going back and forth. Not sure what I am doing wrong in this part of my code.

I have looped my urls in my scraper with playwright to get the XHR response. No issues in that part. The issue is now how do I parse the response.json() thru my parser function and to ensure that it is the final step that is done or rather not to lose any data as this is being done at the same time so I am not sure if I am appending them then doing the parsing in one single go. Which would be the best cast. To do the last parsing of the objects would let me retrieve all json retrivals from all input urls in one go. However, as you can see I get the following error:

Exception in callback AsyncIOEventEmitter._emit_run.._callback(<Task finishe...osing scope")>) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyee_asyncio.py:55
handle: <Handle AsyncIOEventEmitter._emit_run.._callback(<Task finishe...osing scope")>) at C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyee_asyncio.py:55>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyee_asyncio.py", line 62, in _callback
self.emit('error', exc)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyee_base.py", line 116, in emit
self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyee_base.py", line 86, in _emit_handle_potential_error
raise error
File "d:\Projects\AXS\ticketbuylinktest.py", line 33, in handle_response
asyncio.create_task(data_parse(dataarr))
NameError: free variable 'data_parse' referenced before assignment in enclosing scope

I understand that I am suppose to move this but I am not sure where it should be moved to ensure that it does the task last.

```
import ast
from asyncio import tasks
import json
from operator import contains
from urllib import response
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import asyncio

urlarr = ['http://shop.samplesite.com/?c=XXX&e=10254802429572333','http://shop.samplesite.com/?c=XXXX&e=10254802429581183']

proxy_to_use = {"server": "http://myproxy.io:19992","username": "XXXXX","XXXX": "XXXXX"}

dataarr = []
    
finaldata = []
async def main(url):

    print("\n\n\n\nURL BEING RUNNED",url)

    async def handle_response(response):

        l = str(response.url)
        checkstring = 'utm_cid'
        para = '/veritix/Inv/v2/'
        if para in l:
            filterurl = response.url
            if checkstring in filterurl:
                print(response.url)
                await asyncio.sleep(5)
                data = await response.json()
                print("\n\n\n\nDATA:",data)
                dataarr.append(data)
                asyncio.create_task(data_parse(dataarr)) 
    
    

    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        
        
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch(
                        headless=False,)

        page = await browser.new_page(user_agent='My user agent')
                    
                    # Data Extraction Code Here
                    
        page.on("response",lambda response: asyncio.create_task(handle_response(response)))
        

        await page.goto(url) 
        await page.wait_for_timeout(3*5000)
        await browser.close()

        #print("\n\n\n\n",dataarr)      
        

    async def data_parse(dataarr):
           
        jsond = json.dumps(dataarr,indent=2)
        jsonf = json.loads(jsond)
        eventid = jsonf[0]['offerPrices'][0]['zonePrices'][0]['eventID']
        sectiondata = jsonf[0]['offerPrices'][0]['zonePrices'][0]['priceLevels']
        subdata = []
        subdata.append(eventid)
            
        for sec in sectiondata:
                
            section = sec['label']
            inventorycount = sec['availability']['amount']
            price = (sec['prices'][0]['base'])/100
            subdata.extend([section,inventorycount,price])
        finaldata.append(subdata)

    print(finaldata)
    

async def go_to_url():
    tasks = [main(url) for url in urlarr]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(go_to_url())
```

Comment: I suspect that your indentation isn’t accurate.